# Как реализовать отскок от границ экрана?

Tags: c#, wpf, экран

Как в WPF реализовать отскок от границ экрана? (Экран потом что wpf разворачивается на весь экран) 
В WinForm получилось так:

```
if (picEnot.Left <= Ground.Left)
{
    speedLeft = -speedLeft;
}
```

и тд с каждой стороной.

`Ground` - это панель, `speed` - скорость перемещения, `picEnot` - перемещаемая картинка по таймеру.

В WPF удалось реализовать движение по таймеру через `margin`. Но как ограничить экран я не понимаю.

Comment: А почему Margin? Почему вы не пользуетесь `Canvas` в качестве контейнера? И почему нельзя точно так же проверить координаты?

Comment: Потому что я смотрю на WPF не больше суток и не понимаю эти контролы

Comment: Ну так прочитайте какую-нибудь [книгу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105). [Представьте себе водителя грузовика, который на полной скорости начинает спрашивать, как переключать передачу.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте так:

1. В качестве контейнера используйте `Canvas`.
2. Положение на `Canvas`'е устанавливайте при помощи `Canvas.Left` и `Canvas.Top` (выясните, как устанавливать значение attached property).
3. Выход за границу слева и сверху проверяется очевидным образом.
4. Для проверки выхода за границу справа и снизу вам нужно точно знать ширину и высоту вашего объекта (в крайнем случае покатит свойство `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`). Прибавьте к координате левой стороны объекта его ширину, получите правую. Сравните её с правой координатой контейнера (которую можно вычислить точно так же).

Comment: Что проверяется очевидным образом, это понятно.
Только я не понимаю, как это написать кодом.

 На WinForm получилось более, чем быстро. Но из-за специфики "графики" нужен wpf.

Comment: @Viewed: Ну, вы ведь сами присваиваете новое значение `Canvas.Left`? Вот и проверьте перед присвоением, чтобы оно не было меньше нуля.

Comment: Что-то наметилось... 

Уверен, что можно упростить. Не посмотрите?

Comment: @Viewed: Показывайте!

Comment: [скриншот](http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1454610183/1fbeac59/11337295_m.png)

Не нули, так как при них небольшая часть изображения зрительно уходит за предел экрана.
Изначально скорость 100, так как это начальное местоположения картинки

Comment: @Viewed: Переменная `speedTop` означает по сути `PositionY`?

Comment: X или Y это я уже совсем запутался. Но да speed это то или иное положение.

Comment: @Viewed: Вы могли бы вместо `Canvas.GetLeft(Enot)` использовать `speedLeft`, они ж равны по идее.

Comment: Но как это повлияет на картинку?

Comment: @Viewed: А ещё, почему вы сравниваете с `SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth`? Вы должны по идее сравнивать с шириной `Canvas`, разве нет?

Comment: @Viewed: На картинку — никак.

Comment: Во первых, потому что все происходит "на весь экран". Во вторых, потому что с шириной Canvas у меня ничего не получилось

Comment: Почему не получилось? Вы пользовались, я надеюсь, `canvas.ActualWidth`?

Comment: Не-а) 
PrimaryScreen тоже подходит

Никаких предложений по упрощению?

Comment: @Viewed: Вроде проще некуда.

Comment: @Viewed: Кстати, `PrimaryScreen` подходит только если у юзера всего один монитор. Или несколько мониторов с одинаковым разрешением. Так что...

Comment: Больше и не надо.
Но картинка будет не одна, поэтому попробую все это сделать более универсальным